# Associating a custom UICollectionViewController with a subview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a view controller in my main page, which includes a tableview;
in the row of the tableview, I have dragged and added a collection view.

In the storyboard I can click drag the delegate and data source of the collection view to the main view controller (easy enough).

However I like to bind these to a custom subclass of UICollectionViewController (to have a self contained MVC for collections) and not reply on the main page's view controller. How can I do this? (associate custom controller class with the collection view?)

Would I have to use a container view controller? What is the right approach for something like this?

I am newbie to iOS and would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could drag a container view into the row, instead of the collection view.  Then drag the collection view into the container's associated view controller scene.  Change the class (in InterfaceBuilder's identity inspector tab on right) to be your custom view controller class.

--- end of answer ---
Now with that said, consider embracing more of an MVVM approach than MVC.  By this I mean simply to not bother splitting out to separate view controllers for the sake of MVC, but instead to keep all your view controllers simple.  Have each own one (or more) ViewModels, where all the business logic lives that's associated with that view controller. Each ViewModel (which is just an NSObject or even a Swift struct if you wish) can be independently unit tested without involving any UI at all.  The view controllers just literally wire up the data from the ViewModels to the controls & views, and configures the controls & views while relying on the viewModel for any decision-making. It'll radically improve your architecture for minimal effort. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! So to confirm--MVVM aside--dragging a container view seems to be the "proper or standard" mechanism to handle this type nested architecture, that is of course if you don't want to pollute the parent page's view controller with managing the subviews. I imagine there is a benefit to the "container view" approach too: nested view would be somewhat treated as self-contained widgets (better component sharing).

Comment: Yes, container views are the way to split up a scene into using multiple view controllers.  Note that the "container view" is really just a UIView, but one that the storyboard treats differently, such that the storyboard reminds itself to instantiate a separate UIViewController for that UIView at load time.  As for your second "benefit", you already had nested views in the sense of the views you had within your cell view.  Although I'll grant you that seeing the container view as a separate scene in the storyboard can help you stay better organized within the storyboard.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your reply.